# Calling API when div is in viewport?

Tags: angular, viewport, angular2-services

Im trying to achieve scrolling pagination in angular 2. Im calling a API when div is in view-port. I have tried with below code. there is an issue in this process. when div is in view port API is calling continuously. But I want to call API second time after the first API got response. currently its calling continuously when div is in viewport. How to fix this?

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit { 

    getY(element: HTMLElement) {
        let y = element.offsetTop;

        while (element.offsetParent && element.offsetParent != document.body) {
            element = <HTMLElement>element.offsetParent;
            y += element.offsetTop;
        }
        return y;
    }

    getElementOnScreen(selector: string, delta: number = 1.3): any {
        let windowH = self.innerHeight;
        let windowY = self.pageYOffset;
        let margin = windowH * delta;   

        return Array
            .from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
            .find(el => {
            let elementY = this.getY(el as HTMLElement);
            let elementH = el.clientHeight;
            let topOnScreen = (elementY - windowY) <= margin;
            let bottomOnScreen = (windowY + margin) <= (elementY + elementH);

            return topOnScreen && bottomOnScreen;
            });
    }

    onScreen$(selector: string): Observable<boolean> {

       if(this.getElementOnScreen(selector)){         
           let elements='';
           this.inview(elements);      
           return Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll').distinctUntilChanged();     
       }

    }



    inview(eventtest) {   
            calling api;
    }
}
```

**list-component.html**

```
    <div id="test" [class.i-am-in-viewport]="onScreen$('div#test') |async" style="clear: both;height:200px;">
         <div class="load_more" >       
            <p>Loading more results...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should trigger an event only when the scroll reaches the bottom of the page, not when you see the div

Comment: @trichetriche, How to do that in my code?

Comment: Look for infinite scrolls tutorials on Google. I've found one, but it's in French : [click here](https://buzut.fr/creer-un-scroll-infini-en-jquery/) (if you want the logic, scroll down until you see the **JQuery !** title)